# How to protect from malicious use of jQuery post handler?

Tags: php, jquery, post

I use jquery POST calls to fetch data to display in various sections of my websites.

Usually, they POST to a single 'ajax_handler.php' page which reads the requested parameters and returns the relevant data.  Typical parameters might be 'get_order_details',123

How could I stop users posting to the script to try and retrieve data which they should not be able to? I know I can verify that data belongs to the currently logged in user, for instance, but how could I stop users 'guessing' that there might be a handler for 'get_some_info'?

Since users could even run javascript straight from the URL this seems to be a major security problem to me as the client would have access to SESSION and COOKIE data (which I would otherwise use for security).

I guess I could start by naming each of my handler identifiers with a random string, but I'd prefer not to compromise the legibility of my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naming your handlers with a random string is security through obscurity and while it might slow someone down, it won't stop them.

The best thing to do is to store a session or database checksum each time a page is accessed. Then also send that same checksum along with the POST content. When the form is submitted, through AJAX or otherwise, you compare the checksums. If they don't match then you know the user wasn't on the appropriate page and is trying to access the handler through some other method.

Comment: I've read about these 'auth tokens', but if the user runs javascript through the address bar, the auth token will be passed/accessed in exactly the same way, making it redundant. Unless I'm mis-understanding something?

Comment: This is a crappy thing to do to your users, and it isn't how the Internet is supposed to work. It is also security through obscurity, since the user can easily see whatever "checksum" you're providing with each request...

Comment: @cusimar9 - no, they would have to load the proper page first to get the token. True they could go to page, view source, get the token but at that point what does it matter if they submit the request by typing it in the address bar? This method prevents them from "hotlinking" a request.  For it to work you need to regenerate the parameter for every request. So if they have access to a particular database ID they could still get every ID but not in an automatic fashion, at the very least they have to load the entire page each time.

Comment: @meagar - what a silly statement. I suppose you think we should get rid of passwords and accounts and just let everyone link to whatever data they want. This should be transparent to a legitimate user but prevent a nefarious user from obtaining data they aren't supposed to. Or worse a nefarious person crafting a link or image and doing all sorts of nasty things to a user's account without their knowledge. Google XSRF attacks

Comment: No, I'm specifically arguing in favor of passwords and accounts. So long as a user is authenticated, trying to control *how* they access their data is futile.

Answer (score 1):

For each user, you can store within your database which data he should be able to view and which he shouldn't. Each time you get a request, e.g get_order_details, you should call a function which does your security checking to make sure both that the user is logged in, and that he has access to the 'get_order_details' method or any other method he is trying to access.

Comment: I know I can verify the user but I'm talking about functionality which doesn't require a user to be logged in

Comment: @cusimar You can assign each visitor of your site a temporary user id, and use that to track which sections he has loaded. Run a script on Cron every 24 hours to delete the temporary accounts that created 24 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is fundamentally antithetical to how the Internet works. You can't and shouldn't attempt to limit the way users make requests to your services. This is an extremely outdated and backwards way of thinking. Instead of trying to limit the ways in which users can use your service, be thankful that they're using your service in the first place.

All you can do is make sure that the user is authenticated and has access to the record they're requesting. If you're using a system which has no authentication, and you want to prevent users from "guessing" the ID of the next record, don't use sequential IDs. Use randomly generated strings as your identifier. Make them sufficiently long that it will be difficult for users to stumble upon other records.